# Load iframe from external host by javascript

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, cross-domain

I want to embed my widget to any website using javascript. 
There is example of page with my embedding code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Main Frame</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mydomain.com/loadScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>test block</div>
    <div id="widget"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

File loadScript.js on my domain looks this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var container = document.getElementById('widget'),
    iframe = document.createElement('iframe'),
    src = 'http://mydomain.com/dummy.html';
    iframe.setAttribute('src', src);
    container.appendChild(iframe);
};
```

dummy.html is an embedded content. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
dummy - text
</body>
</html>
```

In all browers that's work, except IE. Here after some reloads page begin to update recursively. For better illustration I've made screencast: http://screencast.com/t/QWKkqZU1y

Page loads correctly at first time and it breaks after reload. Clearing cache fix this, but only before reload.
This is repeated not every time, but stable. Anyone can help me?

Comment: `window.onload = ...` - that's bad, because it might break other load events attached the same way on the target page.